# How to calculate dropdown value jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

**when i select only the first dropdown, the result in #output showing NaN?**
http://jsfiddle.net/boyee007/TJcP4/
i want, if the first dropdown is selected is showing 30 then if both selected will calculate the both value

```
<select id="t_dermal_name">
     <option value="1" rel="30">Between Eyebrows</option>
     <option value="7" rel="30">Individual Line Softening</option>
     <option value="2" rel="30">Lip Contouring</option>
</select>
<select id="t_wrinkle_name">
     <option value="1" rel="30">Between Eyebrows</option>
     <option value="7" rel="30">Individual Line Softening</option>
     <option value="2" rel="30">Lip Contouring</option>
</select>

var output = 0;
var output1 = 0;
if($("#t_dermal_name").val() != 0){
    enter code here`output = $("#t_dermal_name").find('option:selected').attr('rel');
 }
 if($("#t_wrinkle_name").val() != 0){
     output1 = $("#t_wrinkle_name").find('option:selected').attr('rel');
 }
 $("#output").html(parseInt(output) + parseInt(output1));
```

Comment: +1 to the question for using jsfiddle like a pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty to update your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/TJcP4/1/).

Is this the functionality you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You have `t_dermal_name` id repeated twice. You probably meant second one to be `t_wrinkle_name`.

And that's not counting `enter code here`output = ...` part :)

Comment: sorry my bad.. jsut made a change :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `output1` isn't set, so `parseInt(output1)` == NaN (Not A Number). When you add this to any other number (i.e. the value from `parseInt(output)`) the total remains NaN.

You should check that output1 is set before attempting to parse it and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var output=0;
var output2=0;

$("#t_dermal_name").change(function(){
     output = $("this").attr('rel');
});

$("#t_wrinkle_name").change(function(){
     output2 = $("this").attr('rel');
});


$("#output").html(parseInt(output) + parseInt(output1));
```